# JavaScript Parsing Complex JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have the follwing JSON:

```
{  
   "_id":"9876567833",
   "result":{  
      "Mercedes":[  
         {  
            "category_name":"Car"
         },
         {  
            "category_name":"Fast"
         }
      ],
      "BMW":[  
         {  
            "category_name":"Car"
         }
      ]
   }
```

I don't know before "Mercedes" or "BMW" (it could change, this is just for the example).
I need to get "Car", "Fast", "Car".

The JSON is in `categories`
So I tried:

```
    var categoArray = [];
    for(var i =0; i < categories.length; i++){
        for (var idx in categories[i].result) {
               if (categories[i].result[idx].length > 0){
                   categoArray.push(categories[i].result[idx].category_name);
          }
         }
       }
```

But it doesn't work.

[EDIT] It is not the same :[Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

My question is much more complex

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you want the array to look like?

Comment: I would like to have in categoArray :  Car", "Fast", "Car"

Comment: @chridam you are right, just edited, thanks

Comment: You are testing `categories[i].result[idx].length`, which, I assume, you are doing because `categories[i].result[idx]` is an array. Then why are you accessing `categories[i].result[idx].category_name`? Arrays don't have such a property.

Comment: The thing is I would like the stuff in "category_name": like "Car", "Fast", "Car"

Comment: @Jose: Is this what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/3Lx6n2d4/ ? Or this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/5epj4ywu/

Comment: Sorry but nothing happen when I run the jsfiddle

Comment: @Jose: Check the javascript console.

Comment: I understand that. I'm just surprised that you seem to know that `categories[i].result[idx]` is an array (otherwise you wouldn't check `length`) and still try to access `category_name` on the *array* instead on one of its *elements*.

Answer (score 3):

You're close, but you need 1 more loop:

```
var categoArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    for (var key in categories[i].result) {
        for (var j = 0; j < categories[i].result[key].length; j++) {
            categoArray.push(categories[i].result[key][j].category_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still have an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'category_name' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

`categories[i].result[idx]` returns an array, not an object. Therefore, `categories[i].result[idx].category_name` will be `undefined`.

Comment: yes :( TypeError: Cannot read property 'category_name' of undefined